# sending facebook friend invitation using new javascript SDK shows 403 forbidden page but the invitation is sent successfully

Tags: django, facebook

In my django website, I am using the new facebook javascript SDK to allow my users to send friend invitation to their facebook friends.

But When users send the website invitation(after login & selecting friends from the facebook popup), the invitation is send successfully but users see a "**403 Forbidden - Cross Site Request Forgery detected. Request aborted "** page ( at the same url from which the invitation was sent). How to overcome this csrf validation.

The javascript code for the invitation( after loading the facebook SDK ):

```
<script>
function invitePopup() {
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
    // user successfully logged in 
    FB.ui({
        method:'fbml.dialog', 
        fbml: (
            '<fb:request-form action="http://{{site.domain}}{% url account_view %}" method="post" invite="true" type="{{ site.name }}" ' +
                'content="help the world by spreading good ideas. Join the move! <fb:req-choice url=\'http://{{site.domain}}{% url facebook_login %}?facebook_invitation=1\' label=\'Accept\' />" >' +                
                '<fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" bypass="cancel" actiontext="Invite your friends to join {{ site.name }}" /> '+
            '</fb:request-form>'
            ),
            size: { width:640, height:480}, width:640, height:480
        });

    $(".FB_UI_Dialog").css('width', $(window).width()*0.8); // 80% of window width
    } else {
            // user cancelled login
        }
    });    

}
</script>
```

and the triggering part:

```
<a href="#" onclick="invitePopup();" class="facebook">Invite your Facebook friends to join {{ site.name }} </a>
```

There is a workaround I've tried i.e. using csrf_exempt decorator for the view. But I don't want to use it because I'm using more forms in that view which needs csrf protection.

Answer (score 1):

you can include crsf_token like this:

```
 FB.ui({
        method:'fbml.dialog', 
            fbml: (
                '<fb:request-form action="http://{{site.domain}}{% url account_view %}" method="post" invite="true" type="{{ site.name }}" ' +
'content="help the world by spreading good ideas. Join the move! <fb:req-choice url=\'http://{{site.domain}}{% url facebook_login %}?facebook_invitation=1\' label=\'Accept\' />" >'

 + "{% csrf_token %}"+  


'<fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" bypass="cancel" actiontext="Invite your friends to join {{ site.name }}" /> '+
                '</fb:request-form>'
                ),
                size: { width:640, height:480}, width:640, height:480
            });
```

Works perfect for me.

Hf